# Android theme with portrait and landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing my android application (min sdk=9 build=21), I want to make a layout-land/port and values-land/port to adapt the screen orientation. when I create these folders the application crashed and the log point on:

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_pressed_want)));
```

And the layout (in landscape folder) have this msg( missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme (16 similar errors not shown), Couldn't resolve resource @color/grey).

So, I want to know how to fix it and use the color of action bar that I selected.

my logcat:

```
e: 04-18 10:16:56.091  27805-27805/com.nearby.myproj E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nearby.myproj, PID: 27805
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nearby.myproj/com.myproj.projectnearby.princ.Auth}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myproj.projectnearby.princ.Auth.onCreate(Auth.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        atandroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
```

this is my class:

```
public class Auth extends FragmentActivity {
private Button btnstart,btncnxUser,btncnxAdmin;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.auth);
    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.blue_pressed_want)));


    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabledGPS = service
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!enabledGPS) {
        Toast.makeText(Auth.this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Auth.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 Boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
    Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if (is3g) {
        Toast.makeText(Auth.this, "3G connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (isWifi) {
        Toast.makeText(Auth.this, "Wifi connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Auth.this, "Network signal not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Activity transfer to wifi settings
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
    }
    btnstart =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Auth.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btncnxUser =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btncnxuser);
    btncnxUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Auth.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btncnxAdmin =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btncnxadmin);
    btncnxAdmin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Auth.this, Image.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}}
```

auth.xml code, in port mode there is no problem but in landscape mode i have this msg (Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logimage"
    android:layout_width="387px"
    android:layout_height="180px"
    android:layout_marginTop="40px"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_nearby"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnstart"
    android:layout_marginTop="80px"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Start"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/logimage"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btncnxuser"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Connect as user"
    android:layout_marginTop="70px"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnstart"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:id="@+id/txtinfo"
    android:text="You have already account ?"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnstart"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btncnxadmin"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:text="Connect as admin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/btncnxuser"/>
```

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa  
it's done i edited and posted a part of my logcat

Comment: this error is not related to "setBackgroundDrawable" ,  post your oncreate method

Comment: @Heshan Sandeepa the problem is in Auth class and it point in the line that set the color of action bar

Comment: post your auth xml file please

Comment: @Heshan Sandeepa i haven't solved it yet i'm still searching

Comment: your code seems fine , can you explain "And the layout (in landscape folder) have this msg( missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references. Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme (16 similar errors not shown), Couldn't resolve resource @color/grey)."

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa my application work fine without land/port folder with the desire actionbar. when i want to adapt the landscape and portrait mode i juste create 2 folders (layout-land & layout-port). i can't start my application and the actionbar color that i choose disapeare